# Getting unique attributes from dynamoDB table

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am working on a backfill issue where I need to fetch all the unique values for an attribute in a dynamo db table and call a service to add these to the storage of that service. I am thinking of creating a temporary dynamo db table. I can read the original table in a lambda function and write only the unique values in the temp table. Is there any other approach possible?

The dynamo DB table has approximately 1,400,000 rows.

Comment: How many rows do you have in the DynamoDB Table ?

Comment: How much write traffic do you have on the table ?

Comment: Given that you're proposing to scan the entire table, you should test how long it takes to retrieve, say, 1000 items, and then estimate an entire table scan. AWS Lambda has a max timeout of 15 minutes. If this is a production table and you have PITR enabled then consider recovering a backup to a new table, maybe raise the provisioned capacity of that new table, and read from that instead of the original table.

Answer (score 0):

1,400,000 records is not that many. Probably you can just read the table.

You can improve the read by making your attribute a global secondary key. It need not be unique. Then you can read only the attribute in question or check uniqueness.

If the records in your table are constantly updated, you can listen to the DynamoDB update stream and just update your temporary table with the new values.

Using the single table pattern https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EOQqi6Yun7g - your "temporary" table can be just a different primary key prefix.

If you have to scan the table and the process is too long, you can split it to multiple lambda calls by passing around the `LastEvaluatedKey` value (e.g. with a step machine).

Answer (score 0):

1. You can scan the whole table, using projection expression fetch only the relevant columns and extract unique values.
2. One more approach can be, you can take a backup of DynamoDB table to S3 and then process the S3 file to extract unique column values.